# How to update options in Firebase Paging Adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui, android-paging

I am using Firestore Paging Adapter to display posts from Firestore. Initially it shows all the posts. I want to add button that will filter posts, for example for particular date.

```
query = firebaseFirestore.collectionGroup("posts")
                .orderBy("start", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .whereGreaterThan("start", Timestamp.now());


        PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
                .setPageSize(5)
                .build();

        FirestorePagingOptions<MyPost> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<MyPost>()
                .setQuery(query, config, MyPost.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirestorePagingAdapter<MyPost, PostViewHolder>(options){
        ....
        }
```

How can I update options object or the query inside it? I found article that told we can use updateOptions() method in Kotlin, but it is not available in Java.
https://medium.com/firebase-developers/update-queries-without-changing-recyclerview-adapter-using-firebaseui-android-32098b3082b2

Comment: It is available in java.  In fact, the firebaseui library is written in java.  Here is the source code that defines the method: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/5ac863c306a4227340395c1a03d3046e13a2a670/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/paging/FirestorePagingAdapter.java#L69

Comment: IDE highlighted it with red and "Cannot resolve method 'updateOptions' in 'FirestorePagingAdapter''"

Comment: It's hard to say why that is without seeing the minimal, exact/standalone code that reproduces that problem. So please add the code that shows `updateOptions` as non-existent. It'd also help if you show how all variables are declared, especially `adapter`.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.